# adfs authentication failed when open logged in website in different browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer, adfs2.0

Can anyone please explain below:

1) I have logged in on IE with adfs authentication.
2) Try to open same logged in website on chrome but it goes to authentication page.

Why my site is not authenticated on google?

And same happens vise versa.

Using visual studio 2010 and WIF 3.5 to develop website as Relying party.

Comment: They don't share session data or authentication data between completely separate browser instances. Authentication isn't computer based like that. I don't know of any site that could do that...

Answer (score 0):

I think, Your code may be checking for creation of new session when you use change the browser. Try commenting session code in your project. I hope this can help you.